# How do I match destinations in the google maps Distance Matrix

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've got a web app that needs 'distance from me' information for properties displayed on a map.

I'm using googles Distance Matrix Service

```
distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
```

I'm calling the service with one origin and multiple destinations.

```
  var params = {
    origins: [currentLocation],
    destinations: endPoints,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }
  distanceService.getDistanceMatrix(params, saveDistances);
```

My endPoints are an array of `google.maps.LatLng` objects taken from my properties. However when the results are returned they've changed these to addresses, and there's no longer any reference to the `LatLng`'s.

Does anyone know if the Distance Matrix Service guarantees to return results in the same order I sent them? I couldn't see anything in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix). I really don't want to start calling the geocoding services just to match back to my properties (especially as the `LatLng`'s return won't be an exact match)

Comment: The documentation implies they are returned in the order provided.  Do you have any reason to believe they are not in order?  The service is asynchronous, but all the results are returned at once.

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip - I didn't notice such an implication - which bit of the docs are referring to?

Comment: Yes because they are returned *as they are formatted by the geocoder*. I agree that it is not clearly stated in the documentation but as @geocodezip mentioned, they should be in the same order. Maybe you can make a few tests to prove that?

Comment: My quick tests showed it to be true (they are returned in the order sent).

Comment: The tests I've done show the order to be the same.

Comment: OK, perhaps we're just lucky with the current implementation, but it would have been better if the request object could be supplied with a 'correlation identifier' that the response object would repeat/include. Then it would not be necessary to depend on undocumented but implied behavior. I think it is a pity that the origin specified in the request (for example, as LatLng) is 'transformed' into a string by reverse geocoding that geoposition, but not included in the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are returned in the same order they are sent.

That isn't specifically stated, but the way I read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_results) it is implied.

[quick test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4a8411pq/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
var places = [{
  address: "New York, NY",
  lat: 40.7143528,
  lng: -74.0059731
}, {
  address: "Tampa, FL",
  lat: 27.950575,
  lng: -82.4571776
}, {
  address: "Newark, NJ",
  lat: 40.735657,
  lng: -74.1723667
}, {
  address: "Boston, MA",
  lat: 42.3584308,
  lng: -71.0597732
}, {
  address: "Baltimore, MD",
  lat: 39.2903848,
  lng: -76.6121893
}];
var foundlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.65, -73.95); // Brooklyn, NY
var gotoLoc = [];
for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
  gotoLoc.push(new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng));
}
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); //request distance matrix
var outputdiv = document.getElementById('info');

//     var goto = new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng);
function callback(response, status) {
    var distancefield = distancefield;
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var htmlString = "<table border='1'>";
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var c = 0; c < response.rows.length; c++) {
        var results = response.rows[c].elements;
        for (var r = 0; r < results.length; r++) {
          var element = results[r];
          var distancetext = element.distance.text;
          var durationtext = element.duration.text;
          var to = destinations[r];
          htmlString += "<tr><td>" + (r + 1) + "</td><td>" + places[r].address + "</td><td>" + response.originAddresses[c] + "</td><td>" + to + "</td><td>" + distancetext + "</td><td>" + durationtext + "</td></tr>";
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker' + (r + 1) + '.png',
            position: {
              lat: places[r].lat,
              lng: places[r].lng
            },
            map: map
          });
          bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        } //end for r
      } // end for c
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      htmlString += "</table>";
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = htmlString;


    } //end if status=ok
  } //end callback

//    console.log(places);

var map;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: foundlatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: ["San Diego, CA", foundlatlng],
    destinations: gotoLoc,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
  }, callback); //end service.getdistancematrix()


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
tr,
td,
tbody,
table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="info"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be so much more helpful if you could provide an Index/ID with each Origin and Destination that would be returned in the API response?

If the order is guaranteed to be the exact same as sent, I agree that this should work fine.  But this is not stated as guaranteed and it seems to arbitrarily limit Google's ability to order the results in a way that suits them better.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes, as this suggestion is very valuable: if the request object could be supplied with a 'correlation identifier', and if the response object would repeat/include that identifier... it would not be necessary to depend on undocumented / unspecified behavior (that currently is working as you'd expect, but the implementation could change without breaking the API).

Comment: Also, ZERO_RESULTS are sent to the end of the list. So if you have any Lat/Lng that can not be computed by Google then the "same order" solution does not work anymore.